# how to get email id and password of facebook login in facebook graph api using doGraphGet method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am beginner of iphone developer. I want to login in my app through facebook. I have using facebook graph API. I have passed the doGraphGet method but its not give email id and password. I am using below code..

```
-(IBAction)getMeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me" withGetVars:nil];
    NSLog(@"getMeButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

}
```

It returns the response of

id, firstname, lastname, name, link, username , gender but it is not giving email id and password

so, give any suggestion and source code which is apply in my code..

Comment: Do you honestly think Facebook provides a "PWN TEH UZER" API with which random apps can obtain the plaintext password of a user? Perhaps brute-forced from the hashes it's stored in? Huh...

Answer (score 3):

For that, first you need to ask user permission, and setting different permission for Facebook Api.

Have a look at below permission:

```
arrFBPermission = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        @"email",
                        @"user_birthday",
                        @"user_likes",
                        @"user_location",
                        @"user_photos",
                        @"read_stream",                            
                        @"status_update",
                        @"user_about_me",
                        @"read_friendlists",
                        @"friends_about_me",
                        @"friends_birthday",
                        @"friends_photos",
                        nil] retain];
```

Then, as per the latest facebook SDK, you can use the login method as below:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:arrFBPermission
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
                                                 ^(FBSession *session,
                                                   FBSessionState state,
                                                   NSError *error) {
                                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                                 }];
```

After successful login, below delegate method will be called:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState) state
                  error:(NSError *)error
{
}
```

And facebook api will not provide you Password.

Hope, you will get success.

Happy Coding!

Cheers!